# How to use explode to split

Tags: php, html

I need to split a text when users add a new line and put this new line (by HTML) into an array position.

```
<?php
$urlstoafiliate = $_POST['urls'];
$affcj = "http://www.an.com";

$arraylinks = explode("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $urlstoafiliate);
echo $arraylinks[ 0 ];

//echo $nombre;
?>
```

Comment: You need `preg_split()` if you want to split a string using a regular expression. `explode()` is literal strings

Comment: explode does not support a regex, easily discovered by [Reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: okey I use preg_split but what argument to split if newline in the html form

Answer (score 2):

You have need `preg_split()` like this :

```
<?php
  $urlstoafiliate = $_POST['urls'];
  $arraylinks = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $urlstoafiliate);
  print_r($arraylinks);
  // or 
  echo $arraylinks[0]; 
?>
```

More details : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`explode("\n", $urlstoafiliate)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get an array of strings and then I would call [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on each string to remove any trailing `\r` (if any) but also any leading or trailing spaces (the URLs input by the user may have leading and/or trailing spaces, especially when the user copy/paste them from other sources):

```
$arraylinks = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $_POST['urls']));
```